# How to efficiently write 6 line hexagrams horizontally at a capped width?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, optimization

I need to efficiently store/print 6 line symbols at a capped width with efficient timing to build the representation and print. Currently they are stored as a list of objects where the **str** property is a six line hexagram.

I have tried nesting for loops and watched my encoding efficiency vanish.

```py
from enum import Enum
import base64
import random

SOLID = '==========\n'
BROKEN = '====  ====\n'

# Snipped 2D array of hexagrams for lookup table called HEXAGRAMS

SORTED_HEXAGRAMS = sorted(sum(HEXAGRAMS, []), key=lambda h: h.value)

def build_hexagram_output(hexagrams):
    output = "\n"
    for hexagram in hexagrams:
        output += str(hexagram) + "\n"
    return output


def encode(msg, shuffle=False, file=False):
    if shuffle:
        print("Shuffling...")
        shuffled = ''.join(random.sample(B64_CHARACTERS, len(B64_CHARACTERS)))
        print("Key: {}".format(shuffled))
        KEYMAP.update(zip(shuffled, SORTED_HEXAGRAMS))
    else:
        KEYMAP.update(zip(B64_CHARACTERS, SORTED_HEXAGRAMS))
    if file:
        msg = "./" + msg
        with open(msg, 'rb') as f:
            b64_encoded = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8')
    else:
        b64_encoded = base64.b64encode(bytes(msg, encoding='utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    hexagrams = []
    for letter in b64_encoded.replace('=', ''):
        hexagrams.append(KEYMAP[letter])
    return build_hexagram_output(hexagrams)


class Trigram(Enum):
    HEAVEN = 0
    LAKE = 1
    FIRE = 2
    THUNDER = 3
    WIND = 4
    WATER = 5
    MOUNTAIN = 6
    EARTH = 7

    def __str__(self):
        if self.value == 0:
            return SOLID + SOLID + SOLID
        elif self.value == 1:
            return BROKEN + SOLID + SOLID
        elif self.value == 2:
            return SOLID + BROKEN + SOLID
        elif self.value == 3:
            return BROKEN + BROKEN + SOLID
        elif self.value == 4:
            return SOLID + SOLID + BROKEN
        elif self.value == 5:
            return BROKEN + SOLID + BROKEN
        elif self.value == 6:
            return SOLID + BROKEN + BROKEN
        elif self.value == 7:
            return BROKEN + BROKEN + BROKEN

class Hexagram:
    def __init__(self, upper, lower, value):
        self.upper = upper
        self.lower = lower
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.upper) + str(self.lower)
```

I would like its current output:

```
====  ====
==========
====  ====
====  ====
====  ====
====  ====

==========
==========
==========
====  ====
====  ====
==========

====  ====
==========
==========
==========
====  ====
==========
```

To appear horizontally:

```
====  ==== ========== ====  ====
========== ========== ==========
====  ==== ====  ==== ==========
====  ==== ====  ==== ==========
====  ==== ========== ====  ====
====  ==== ========== ==========
```

EDIT:

Thanks to Prune for the correct answer and getting me on the right path. These are not random, but a shift cipher - so I can't necessarily build rows/columns until the whole message is encoded. Here ended up being my final solution. Not the prettiest - but it works well and I ditched spaces for a more obscure output.

```py
def build_hexagram_output(hexagrams):
    output = ""
    lines = [str()] * 6
    for hexagram in hexagrams:
        split_hexagram = str(hexagram).split("\n")
        for i in range(6):
            lines[i] += split_hexagram[i]
    position = 0
    total_position = 0
    while total_position <= len(lines[0]) - 1:
        for line in lines:
            output += line[total_position: total_position + MAX_WIDTH] + "\n"
            if position == 5:
                position = 0
            else:
                position += 1
        total_position += MAX_WIDTH
    return output
```

```
02:27:10 [jonesy@yeetbook] iching > python main.py -e ThanksPrune
==============  ================================================================
====  ================================================  ==================  ====
==============  ============================  ========  ========  ========  ====
==============  ========  ========  ========  ========  ========  ==============
====  ========  ========  ========  ============================  ========  ====
====  ========  ======================================  ========  ========  ====
====  ========  ========  ========  ============================  ====
====  ========  ======================================  ========  ====
==============  ============================  ========  ==============
==============  ==================  ========  ========  ==============
====  ============================  ============================  ====
==============  ======================================  ==============
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the project simply emits random hexagrams, then the simply way is to generate six lines of three symbols each.  Generate the same 18 symbols, but print them in the order generated, with a line break after each group of 3.  Something like

```
import random

for row in range(6):
    line = ""
    for col in range(3):
        line += random.choice(["========== ", "====  ==== "])
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
========== ====  ==== ========== 
========== ========== ========== 
====  ==== ====  ==== ====  ==== 
========== ====  ==== ========== 
====  ==== ====  ==== ====  ==== 
========== ========== ====  ====
```

---

You've gone to a lot of extraneous work to maintain representations your program doesn't use.  If you need to evaluate the trigrams produced, it's easy enough to work instead with the underlying binary code.  Keep the bit for each chosen symbol and turn those back into trigram and hexagram codes *after* the fact:

```
symbol = ["========== ", "====  ==== "]
gram = [""] * 6
for row in range(6):
    line = ""
    for col in range(3):
        bar = random.randint(0, 1)
        line += symbol[bar]
        gram[col] += str(bar)
    print(line)

print(col)
```

You now have `col` as three binary strings, one for each hexagram.  Simply split into trigrams as you wish; convert each number from binary to decimal, and you have your indices for use in analysis.  For the example above, `col` shows as

```
"001010" "101110" "001011"
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Prune. I edited the top post so you can see my final solution. Encoding time is back baby.